# Throw localized ValidationException

Tags: c#, validation

I am creating a custom property validation which should use the error string in the specified resource file when throwing a ValidationException. Am I right in assuming that if I throw an exception and don't specify the error string in the parameters, it should use the ErrorMessageResourceName and ErrorMessageResourceType I specified in the constructor?

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace OurProduct.Util
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public class UniquenessAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public UniquenessAttribute()
        {
            ErrorMessageResourceName = "EmailUniqueError";
            ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (Resources.OurThing);
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value)
        {
            throw new ValidationException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and yes, I'm aware that there's no possibility to return ValidationResult.Success in this example, but I know that works ;)

Comment: It should work, provided OurThing points to the generated strongly-typed resource class, for looking up localized strings, etc, and "EmailUniqueError" is one of the static properties of this class. Also make sure you're validating all properties (if you use TryValidateObject for example, make sure the last parameter is set to true) when doing your tests. But don't throw, just return false to IsValid()

Comment: @SimonMourier Can you elaborate on your last sentence? The reason why I'm using the version of IsValid that requires a ValidationResult is because I need to look up the values of other members of the parent object, to call a service. The problem lies in trying to return a ValidationResult.Success when it's working fine but a properly localized ErrorMessage when it isn't.

Comment: Ok, then you should return something like this: `return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));` in case of an error.

Comment: You are amazing, Simon. Please make this an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work, provided `OurThing` points to the generated strongly-typed resource class, for looking up localized strings, etc, and `"EmailUniqueError"` is one of the static properties of this class:

```
    public class UniquenessAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public UniquenessAttribute()
        {
            ErrorMessageResourceName = "EmailUniqueError";
            ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (Resources.OurThing);
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (failure) // to implement
                return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
            ...
        }
    }
```

Also make sure you're validating all properties (if you use [TryValidateObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.tryvalidateobject.aspx) for example, make sure the last parameter is set to true) when doing your tests.